# error in number of input argument

Tags: matlab, function, substitution

I have a 99*1 symbolic expression array.it has 676 variables that I stored them in 'varsubs'
I convert it to function with

```
 cccc = matlabFunction(sloads , 'vars' , varsubs)
```

I check the number of input arguments with

```
nargin(cccc)
```

and matlab return 676.
after that for test the cccc function I created an array

```
xxxx = ones(1,676)
```

and the substitute that in cccc

```
cccc(xxxx)
```

but I got an error

**Error using

Not enough input arguments.**

Who knows why this error happend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xxxx` is a single array with 676 elements, so you're only actually passing 1 argument. I'm really not sure what exactly you're trying to do but if you really want to pass 676 arguments all equal to one then you need to generated a comma separated list by calling `{:}` on a cell array whose elements are all equal to `1`:

```
xxxx{676} = [];
[xxxx{:}] = deal(1);
cccc(xxxx{:})
```

Comment: thanks Dan for your answer , Do you how I can pass different arguments? (I have my arguments in a single array with 676 elements)

Comment: Just fill the *cell* array `xxxx` with different numbers